# ImageGrab.grab() the second screen while running code on the first screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

As the question says. Can I screenshot the second screen when my script is running on the first screen?
I mean I have the code running on my first screen and I want to capture the second screen only. How do I do it? Of course all done with `ImageGrab.grab()` from `PIL` module.

Comment: It depends on your OS - which you didn't state.

Comment: I have Windows 10 OS.

Comment: I don't have Windows or 2 monitors, but according to this https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageGrab.html you can use `PIL.ImageGrab.grab(bbox=None, include_layered_windows=False, all_screens=True)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question solved!

`PIL.ImageGrab.grab(bbox=None, include_layered_windows=False, all_screens=True)`

And it captures every screen.